# How to know Stackify prefix has been enabled?

Tags: stackify

I am using Stackify Prefix v3.0.28. I can enable it from the system tray. How do I know it has been enabled at any time? I don't see a visual cue in the system tray. I am expecting like a checkmark or something near 'Enable .NET Profiler'. If I enable it again, it doesn't say it's already enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a current way to see if the Profiler is enabled. You can submit an idea on Stackify's ideas portal here: https://ideas.stackify.com/

The COO gets notified when a new request has been made and when a request has been up voted by several clients. He takes each request into good consideration and arranges them into our road map. Also you can subscribe to the ideas to keep updated on its progress.

If you are having any other issues send a message to Stackify Support support@stackify.com